# Xamarin.Forms applications for sharing a text in social media

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, share

Please I need demonstration step by step on how to develop Xamarin.Forms application for sharing a text in social media. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/android), there is a [Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) class enables an application to share data such as text and web links to other applications on the device.

For example:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public class ShareTest
{
    public async Task ShareText(string text)
    {
        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Text = text,
                Title = "Share Text"
            });
    }

    public async Task ShareUri(string uri)
    {
        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Uri = uri,
                Title = "Share Web Link"
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a GitHub repository [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social) and an article [Article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153044/how-to-share-text-and-a-link-with-social-media-in-xamarin-forms-ios) and YouTube video [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0aQJHoI1e8). **I would like to remind you that this website is not for that someone writes a hundred lines of code for you. Just ask errors or issues.**

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thank you for your contributions but here is my code for your kind help.
    Please put me true because I'm new in Xamarin.Forms.
       
    This is my TextPage.xaml:
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="Manytext.File.TextPage"
                 Title="Title">
    
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView>
                    <Label Text="Subheading"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="16,10,16,10" Spacing="10">
                    <Label Text="Many text is here">
                    <Label Text="Many text is here">
                    <Label Text="Many text is here">
                    <Label Text="Many text is here">
    
                    <Button x:Name="ButtonShare"
                            Clicked="ShareText_OnClicked"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Text="Share" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    
    </ContentPage>
    
    This is my TextPage.xaml.cs:
    
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace Manytext.File
{
    public partial class TextPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TextPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void ShareText_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Title = "Share!"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, It posted the empty message.

Comment: Use Text instead of Title.

Comment: I used it but it only send the text information only instead of sending the whole page information. Please i want to share the whole page information to social network from my app.

Comment: If you want to share the whole page information, you can share the page url.